# How to find status of producer using consumer

Tags: java, file, consumer, producer

I am reading a large sized file like approximately 2 GB. But I am not aware of whether the writer has written the file completely. Is there any way to check whether the file is written completely from reader side?

Comment: You can do it in many ways, but you need to provide some code to realy get helped.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code, it's going to be hard to make any concrete suggestions but why not just extend whatever class you're using as a writer and add a simple [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to it (I'm assuming that reader and writer are running in two different threads) and call `countDown()` once writing is done? On the reader side, you simply use the latch's `await` method.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there isn't a portable way to do it.  However on Linux you can test if some other process has a file open by running the `lsof` command and processing its output.

For example:

```
lsof /home/fred/someFile
```

will output the pids for the process or processes that have that file open.  If you can assume that the process that is writing the file closes it once it has finished writing (and doesn't reopen it), you can use the `lsof` output to test if the file has been fully written.

You can run the `lsof` command from Java using `Process` / `ProcessBuilder`.